# How to minimise app in ionic using capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I want to minimise the app on pressing back button in my ionic application that uses capacitor. (To be clear, what i mean by minimise is to trigger the action of 'middle back button' on pressing of 'edge back button'. I hope that this is clear in reference to majority of the android phones.). I found something similar in cordova, (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize). But my application crashes while using it. So is there any capacitor alternative to the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to minimize the app in Capacitor or Ionic directly. However, in Android native code, we can minimize the app by sending it to the background which can be achieved using the `moveTaskToBack()` method.

You would need to create a Capacitor Plugin to execute this Android native code.